# mat-select-filter with dynamic values filter

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I am unable to filter data using mat-select-filter:

```
`<mat-form-field *ngIf="fundComplexesList">
                        <mat-select placeholder="Using array of objects">
                              <mat-select-filter [placeholder]="'Filter'"     [displayMember]="'fundComplexName'" [array]="fundComplexesList" (filteredReturn)="filteredList5   =$event"></mat-select-filter>
                            <mat-option *ngFor="let item of filteredList5" [value]="item">
                                {{item.fundComplexName}}
                            </mat-option>
                        </mat-select>
                    </mat-form-field>`
```

I am getting fundComplexesList  value from the api call

```
    `ngOnInit(): void {
     this.agreementService.getFundComplexes(false).subscribe(data => {
     this.fundComplexesList = data;
    },
    error => {
    console.log('Error while binding FundComplex dropdown.');
    });
 `
```

and this is my filter method:

```
  `public filteredList5 =  this.fundComplexesList.slice();`
```

problem is that I am not getting this.fundComplexesList value when public filteredList5 =  this.fundComplexesList.slice(); function is called, can someone suggest how to get the value in fundComplexesList before calling filteredList5 =  this.fundComplexesList.slice();

Answer (score 0):

**HTML FILE**

```
<mat-form-field *ngIf="fundComplexesList">
 <mat-select placeholder="Using array of objects">
   <mat-select-filter [placeholder]="'Filter'"  [displayMember]="'fundComplexName'" [array]="fundComplexesList" (filteredReturn)="filteredList5   =$event"></mat-select-filter>
     <mat-option *ngFor="let item of filteredList5" [value]="item">{{item.fundComplexName}}
     </mat-option>
    </mat-select>
  </mat-form-field>
```

**TS File**

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
})
export class AppComponent {
  fundComplexesList: any = [];

  public filteredList5: any;
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}
 ngOnInit(): void {
     this.agreementService.getFundComplexes(false).subscribe(data => {
      this.fundComplexesList = data;
      this.filteredList5 = this.fundComplexesList.slice();
},
error => {
    console.log('Error while binding FundComplex dropdown.');
   });
  }
}
```